# Sampling from activity pattern probability density function

Tags: r, resampling

I'm trying to  randomly sampling 1000 times from the observed activity pattern probability density function of a specie activity (see image for example).
[image]

I'm using package activity in R with this code :

```
leopard<-activityDensity(recordTable = dat,
                      species     = "Leopard_African",
                      recordDateTimeCol="imeOriginal",
                      recordDateTimeFormat ="%H:%M:%S",
                      adjust = 0.185)
```

Here is the result of dput :

```
 c(1.5070918090971, 1.65719012476862, 0.000290888208665722, 
 1.32106879965537, 
 6.258896141756, 1.33219527363684, 1.61937465764207, 0.389281145246902, 
 6.17584755818193, 5.16552008743372, 1.24645597413262, 5.18442782099699, 
 1.60686646466945, 2.11090300823497, 1.17453386454002, 5.65144884000981, 
 1.281144393016, 3.75609399439613, 0.207476014830826, 1.20842234084957, 
 5.7775488784664, 5.35605186410976, 5.29082018331648, 5.35248848355361, 
6.22035345410779, 1.55436114300528, 1.19780492123328, 5.2116985905594, 
5.10392450924875, 5.73609730873153, 6.07061874869711, 0.590721229747914, 
5.38332263367218, 0.418369966113474, 1.08290407881032, 0.943932237120267, 
2.0423988350942, 4.79245595981993, 0.274453024876108, 5.00640423729357, 
5.01222200146688, 1.16297105824555, 5.83565379814737, 0.0757763783574205, 
5.36935999965622, 1.01629067902586, 1.03068964535482, 1.71427693571926, 
2.07890530528175, 0.660825288036353, 1.18566033852148, 1.59174027781883, 
5.44928153498713, 5.24878683716428, 0.327540122957602, 1.37808288855386, 
5.83412663505188, 5.41502944841674, 0.443240907954393, 5.64330397016716, 
1.75267417926314, 5.66912029868625, 0.856520330416217, 5.1506120667396, 
0.807723833412542, 5.9616811145518, 0.450804001379702, 0.905098661263393, 
5.19322718930913, 1.18944188523414, 1.74416569915967, 6.21228130631732, 
5.99055176926187, 1.74605647251599, 2.31241581478815, 5.12326857512502, 
6.16712091192196, 5.66788402379942, 5.4172838320339, 5.14341258357512, 
1.28798026591965, 6.11890619133562, 0.570504499245646, 0.908516597715215, 
5.5084772854506, 0.508763476956347, 5.2004266724736, 1.3862277583965, 
1.53952584436333, 1.55188859323162, 1.55581558404861, 5.4166293335644, 
0.358665161284835, 0.459457925587507, 5.97520741625475, 5.48447900823568, 
0.946113898685259, 1.3738650095282, 0.744891980340746)
```

But now I have no idea how to do the sampling part. The idea is to get a boxplot for each hour with the expected probability. You can see an example in the image below :
[image]

This procedure might help :Each iteration of the randomisation procedure implemented the following steps for every detection of a species (other than lion): 1) a new date was selected at random from the survey period of the corresponding camera trap; 2) a new time was selected by sampling the activity pattern probability density function for the corresponding species; 3) the number of hours separating the randomised proximal detections and the unchanged reference ones was derived. This resulted in 1000 expected values of detection probability for each day (10 days before and after a lion detection), which we compared to the observed value using a standard permutation test. The latter computed the two-tailed probability P = (ne Accepted Article + 1)/N of getting a value that was more or less than the observed level, where N is the ‘This article is protected by copyright. All rights reserved.’ total number expected values and ne is the number of values lesser or greater than the observed. All statistical tests were performed based a significance level of α = 0.05.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi Rob, if you can share some sample data with `dput` it'll be easier to help out! I feel like there might be some very simple, naive bootstrapping ways to do what you're talking about but they may rely on the assumption that your data are sufficiently representative in risky ways.

Comment: would the `recdf` function from the `litteR` package give you what you need?

Comment: Hi @MichaelRoswell, thanks for answering. I'm pretty sur solution is easy but can't figure how to do it with boxplot for a specific timeframe. I've edited the question to put the result of dput in it. Thanks again